# regex and substitution in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to strip and replace a text string that looks as follows in the most elegant way possible:

```
element {"item"} {text { 
          } {$i/child::itemno}
```

To look like:

```
<item> {$i/child::itemno}
```

Hence removing the element text substituting its braces and removing text and its accompanying braces.

I believe the appropriate regex to do this is:

```
/element\s*\{"([^"]+)"\}\s*{text\s*{\s*}\s*({[^}]*})/
```

but I am unsure as to the number of backslashes to use in java and also how to complete the final substitution which makes use of my group(1) and replaces it with < at its start and > at its end:

So far I have this (although perhaps I might be better off with a full rewrite ?)

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/element\\s*\\{\"([^\"]+)\"\\}\\s*{text\\s*{\\s*}\\s*({[^}]*})/ "); 
             // Split input with the pattern 
        Matcher m = p.matcher("element {\"item\"} {text {\n" + 
                "          } {$i/child::itemno} text { \n" + 
                "            } {$i/child::description} text {\n" + 
                "            } element {\"high_bid\"} {{max($b/child::bid)}}  text {\n" + 
                "        }}  ");
```

// Next for each instance of group 1, replace it with < > at the start

---

I think I've stumbled across a problem. What I am trying to do is somewhat harder than I previously stated. With the solution I have below:

```
element {"item"} {text { } {$i/child::itemno} text { } {$i/child::description} text { } element {"high_bid"} {{max($b/child::bid)}} text { }}
```

GIVES:

```
<item> {$i/child::itemno} text { } {$i/child::description} text { } element {"high_bid"} {{max($b/child::bid)}} text { }}
```

When I expected:

```
<item>{$i/child::itemno}{$i/child::description}<high_bid>{fn:max($b/child::bid)}</high_bid></item>
```

Comment: This is going to be very, very painful.

Comment: It doesn't have to be :P I've probably over convoluted the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Java regex-es are written without delimiters. So lose the forward slashes;
2. every single backslash needs one extra, so `\s` becomes `\\s`;
3. all `{` need to be escaped: `\\{`, and `}` need no escape (although it doesn't hurt if you do escape them).

Try:

```
String text = "element {\"item\"} {text { } {$i/child::itemno}";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("element\\s*\\{\"([^\"]+)\"}\\s*\\{text\\s*\\{\\s*}\\s*(\\{[^}]*})", "<$1> $2"));
```

Output:

```
<item> {$i/child::itemno}
```

Comment: Thanks ! that works a treat (and relatively painless I think !)

Comment: You're welcome. The painfulness depends on how proficient you are with regex. Someone unfamiliar with regex is likely to disagree with you. :)